# arm-linux-androideabi-gcc gives png.h error

Tags: android, android-ndk, libpng

I am getting this error while run configure script with Android NDK-standalone toolchain for a 3rd part C library.

```
configure:3463: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:19:17: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
#include <png.h>
```

How do I include png.h to arm-linux-androideabi-gcc compiler toolchain?

Answer (score 0):

I found this article helpful: http://blog.stuff-o-matic.com/post/2013/09/07/Porting-a-C-game-to-Android,-the-case-of-Andy-s-Super-Great-Park